# how to disable all breakpoints at once in DDD debugger (pydb mode)

Tags: debugging, gdb, breakpoints, ddd-debugger

Using gdb, we can disable breakpoints as explained on ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_node/gdb_32.html. On the document, to disalbe all the breakpoints it says to give just `disalbe` without the breakpoint list. But in my ddd(data-display-debuger), it doesn't work. How can I do it? Or how can I specify the range? (I tried 1-10 but didn't work).

EDIT : I was using DDD for python debugging using command `ddd -pydb prog.py arg1 arg2..` so it was actually pydb command, not gdb command. See the comments for the answer, and I later found that for pydb, the command `delete` without any argument deletes all the breakpoints. For disabling all the breakpoints, you have to modify gdb.py and see comments below.

Comment: I saw `disable 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9` works.

Comment: It works for me (ddd 3.3.12, gdb 7.7.1). What version are you running?

Comment: GNU DDD 3.3.12 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) and 
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.2-83.el6). Probably GDB version difference?

Comment: I'll see if I have those versions. If you type `info b`, then `disable`, then `info b` again, are there any differences at all in the output? Not even one breakpoint has an `n` in the `Enb` column?

Comment: (Pydb) disable
*** No breakpoint number given.

Comment: Oh. You're not using gdb, you're using pydb. pydb's command set is inspired by gdb's, but they aren't the same. But pydb is easy to modify, since it comes with all the source code, written in python. Look for `do_disable` in `gdb.py` and change `self.errmsg('No breakpoint number given.')` to something like `for bp in bdb.Breakpoint.bpbynumber: bp.disable()`.

Comment: Oh, that was so. please move your comment to an answer so that I can mark it as the selected answer. thanks!

Comment: Correct fix was : for bp in bdb.Breakpoint.bpbynumber:
                if bp:
                    bp.disable(),   The same for do_enable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commands supported by pydb are similar to those in gdb, but they aren't all the same. Currently, pydb's *disable* command gives an error if no arguments are given. You can edit pydb's source code (it may be found in `/usr/share/pyshared/pydb/` on many systems) and change `do_disable` (in `gdb.py`) so that if no args are given to *disable*, it will disable all breakpoints:

```
*** gdb.py.orig 2009-11-17 17:00:21.000000000 -0800
--- gdb.py  2016-08-20 17:12:09.561338798 -0700
***************
*** 1067,1069 ****
          if len(args) == 0:
!             self.errmsg('No breakpoint number given.')
              return
--- 1067,1071 ----
          if len(args) == 0:
!             for bp in bdb.Breakpoint.bpbynumber:
!                 if bp:
!                     bp.disable()
              return
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm using it conveniently now.. :)